# How To get value of SeekBar and use it on another class or method

Tags: android, kotlin, seekbar

I'm new in Kotlin and I want to use three Seekbar on my app for RGB control;
I want to set seekBarManger function to manage my seekbar on SeekBarManger class and use seekbar.progress value on other class
but I cant get value of my seekbar.
the Toast is Show but I want to use the value of seekbar.progrees in other method and class.
please help me..!!!!
this is my seekbar class :

```
class SeekBarManager()  {


}

fun seekBarManage(context: Context, seekBar: SeekBar) {



   seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(object : SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener {


       override fun onProgressChanged(p0: SeekBar?, p1: Int, p2: Boolean) { }

       override fun onStartTrackingTouch(p0: SeekBar?) {}

       override fun onStopTrackingTouch(p0: SeekBar?) {


           val result = seekBar.progress

           Toast.makeText(context, "Progress is: $result%", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()


       }


   })
```

and this is my MainActivity :

```
open class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity()  {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)


        val seekRed  = findViewById<SeekBar>(R.id.seekBar_red)
        val seekGreen = findViewById<SeekBar>(R.id.seekBar_green)
        val seekBlue = findViewById<SeekBar>(R.id.seekBar_blue)
        
        val seekEndRed = seekBarManage(this , seekRed)
        val seekEndGreen = seekBarManage(this , seekGreen)
        val seekEndBlue = seekBarManage(this , seekBlue)
```

the Toast is Show but I want to use the value of seekbar.progrees in other method and class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the easiest way is to use a companion object in your Main class and just call a method and pass your seek bar object like below :

```
open class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    companion object {
        fun getSeekBarProgress(context: Context, seekBar: SeekBar) {
            val result = seekBar.progress
            Toast.makeText(context, "Progress is: $result%", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

    }
}

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)


        val seekRed = findViewById<SeekBar>(R.id.seekBar_red)
        val seekGreen = findViewById<SeekBar>(R.id.seekBar_green)
        val seekBlue = findViewById<SeekBar>(R.id.seekBar_blue)

        val seekEndRed = seekBarManage(this, seekRed)
        val seekEndGreen = seekBarManage(this, seekGreen)
        val seekEndBlue = seekBarManage(this, seekBlue)
    }
}
```

and SeekBarManager class :

```
class SeekBarManager() {


}

    fun seekBarManage(context: Context, seekBar: SeekBar) {


    seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(object : SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener {


        override fun onProgressChanged(p0: SeekBar?, p1: Int, p2: Boolean) {}

        override fun onStartTrackingTouch(p0: SeekBar?) {}

        override fun onStopTrackingTouch(p0: SeekBar?) {

            MainActivity.getSeekBarProgress(context, seekBar)

        }


    })
    }
```

Comment: thank you for answer my question , sorry I'm new user in stackoverflow and I 'm edit my question, can you answer my question again????

Comment: your welcome, please open a new question for the next problem, because in this state everybody thinks that your problem is solved and no one else looks at your question.

Comment: thanks for guidance . I'm open a new question. can you answer that!!!!!?????